# D3js Bind path `d` attribute to data

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I'm trying to find the proper way to dynamically generate a path. I'm following [DashingD3js' pattern](https://www.dashingd3js.com/svg-paths-and-d3js) for creating SVG Paths with D3js.

My question is, apart from checking each index in the accessor function and manipulating the value, and apart from creating variables that represent specific points that I want to manipulate, is there an easier way to specify dynamic line coordinates?

I have my coordinates for the path in an array of objects. I'm easily able to make the coordinates responsive using `w` and `h` values.

```
var lineData = [ {'x': 100, 'y': 0 }, {'x': w/2, 'y': -150 }, {'x': w/2, 'y': 150}, {'x': 100, 'y': 0}];
```

I've been able to manipulate the coordinates somewhat via the accessor function like the following.

```
var lineFunction = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function(d, i) {

            // function replacing lineData w/dynamic data

          } 
          return d.x 
        })
        .y(function(d) { return d.y })
        .interpolate('linear');
```

Here's how I reference the path:

```
myPath
    .attr('d', function() { return lineFunction(lineData); });
```

Is there an easier way to specify dynamic line coordinates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If some of the values in the `linedata` array are dynamic then their values should reflect that.

For example...

```
function f () {return w/2;}; //assuming w is updated asynchronously
var lineData = [ {'x': 100, 'y': 0 }, {'x': f, 'y': -150 }, {'x': f, 'y': 150}, {'x': 100, 'y': 0}];
```

Then you just need to make the accessor aware that some of the values are functions...

```
var lineFunction = d3.svg.line()
.x(function(d, i) {
    return typeof d.x === "function" ? d.x() : d.x;
  })
.y(function(d) { return d.y })
.interpolate('linear');
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Did you pick this up somewhere or is this your own implementation?

Comment: Sorry, I have no reference for this, it's just my idea of how to do it based on [generally accepted principles](https://media.pragprog.com/articles/may_04_oo1.pdf). The principle here is "shy": there is a global rule based on `w` that only `f` needs to know, some of the members of `linedata` accept this global value, but only `linedata` needs to know which and in order to parse these members, `linefunction` needs to know that some of the members are functions. So you just figure out which objects need to know what and take it from there.